# "Could not complete the operation" when trying to add an authorized network to Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to add an authorized network to our cloud sql instance, but each time I click `Save` I get told `Could not complete the operation`. That's it unfortunately, there's no explanation as to what the problem might be.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it was a GCP issue. Waited a few hours and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is looking here, I found this could mean that you've reached your daily quota of cloud sql api queries. The quota starts at 100k per day and it resets at midnight pacific time.